# Python code in order to groupby and return all occurences that are found in the data

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Assume that my data is:

```
my_list=[[0,'A',10,12,14],
         [0,'A',10,13,15],
         [0,'A',8,12,13],
         [0,'A',9,13,17],
         [0,'A',8,11,15],
         [0,'B',9,5,7],
         [0,'B',11,5,9],
         [0,'B',8,7,8],
         [1,'A',11,14,9],
         [0,'B',8,10,14],
         [1,'B',11,6,6],
         [1,'A',10,5,9]
         [1,'B',9,6,6]]

my_frame=pd.DataFrame(my_list, columns=['id','quality','grade','characteristic 1','characteristic 2'])
```

My aim is to group my data by 'id' and 'quality' using the grade as the max and min value of interest. So I code:

```
my_group=np.array(my_frame.groupby(['id','quality'])['grade']
         .agg(["max grade", max],["min grade", min])
         .reset_index())
```

So far so good, but I have not figured out how to deal with what I really need as information:

I would like to group and get all cases that grade max and min occurs, with all the information of the row. In other words, the code that currently works for me gives me this:

```
print(my_group)
```

Output:

```
[[0,'A',10,8],
 [0,'B',11,8],
 [1,'A',11,10],
 [1,'B',11,9]]
```

However, what I am interested in is to bring this kind of output:

```
[[0,'A',10,12,14],
 [0,'A',10,13,15],
 [0,'A',8,12,13],
 [0,'A',8,11,15],
 [0,'B',11,5,9],
 [0,'B',8,7,8],
 [0,'B',8,10,14],
 [1,'A',11,14,9],
 [1,'A',10,5,9],
 [1,'B',11,6,6],
 [1,'B',9,6,6]]
```

To make it as clear as possible, the groupby will bring me the max and the min 'grade' per 'id' and per 'quality', but I actually need to know the rest of the information ('characteristic 1' and 'characteristic 2') that I get this max and min 'grade', regardless how many times the max 'grade' and min 'grade' appear.

Could you please guide me through this? I hope my question is clear.

Comment: Can you please include the desired output and explain a bit more clearly the logic by which you arrive there?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: I am trying to update it. New to this and pressed something that actually posted it before I finish it.

Comment: There is a comma missing behind the last-but-one vector of `my_list` btw.

Comment: @Newbielp shouldn't the row `0, 'B', 8, 10, 14` be in your desired output?  8 is in the minimum for group `(0, 'B')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Updated solution, I think you need this:

```
my_frame[my_frame.groupby(['id','quality'])['grade']\
                 .transform(lambda x: (x == x.min()) | (x == x.max()))]\
                 .sort_values(['id','quality'])
```

Output:

```
    id quality  grade  characteristic 1  characteristic 2
0    0       A     10                12                14
1    0       A     10                13                15
2    0       A      8                12                13
4    0       A      8                11                15
6    0       B     11                 5                 9
7    0       B      8                 7                 8
9    0       B      8                10                14
8    1       A     11                14                 9
11   1       A     10                 5                 9
10   1       B     11                 6                 6
12   1       B      9                 6                 6
```

And, converted to 2d array:

```
my_frame[my_frame.groupby(['id','quality'])['grade']\
                 .transform(lambda x: (x == x.min()) | (x == x.max()))]\
                 .sort_values(['id','quality']).values.tolist()
```

Output:

```
[[0, 'A', 10, 12, 14],
 [0, 'A', 10, 13, 15],
 [0, 'A', 8, 12, 13],
 [0, 'A', 8, 11, 15],
 [0, 'B', 11, 5, 9],
 [0, 'B', 8, 7, 8],
 [0, 'B', 8, 10, 14],
 [1, 'A', 11, 14, 9],
 [1, 'A', 10, 5, 9],
 [1, 'B', 11, 6, 6],
 [1, 'B', 9, 6, 6]]
```

---

IIUC, you want to join back the results of your groupby aggregation to your original dataframe:

```
my_frame.merge(my_frame.groupby(['id','quality'])['grade']
                       .agg(['max','min', lambda x: x.max()-x.min()]), 
               left_on=['id','quality'], 
               right_index=True).values.tolist()
```

Output:

```
[[0, 'A', 10, 12, 14, 10, 8, 2],
 [0, 'A', 10, 13, 15, 10, 8, 2],
 [0, 'A', 8, 12, 13, 10, 8, 2],
 [0, 'A', 9, 13, 17, 10, 8, 2],
 [0, 'A', 8, 11, 15, 10, 8, 2],
 [0, 'B', 9, 5, 7, 11, 8, 3],
 [0, 'B', 11, 5, 9, 11, 8, 3],
 [0, 'B', 8, 7, 8, 11, 8, 3],
 [0, 'B', 8, 10, 14, 11, 8, 3],
 [1, 'A', 11, 14, 9, 11, 11, 0],
 [1, 'B', 11, 6, 6, 11, 11, 0]]
```

Comment: But then I get row[3] -starting from [0]- which has info [0, 'A', 9, 13, 17, 10, 8, 2], which I do not want, because 9 < 10 and 9 > 8, so it should not be in the output.

Comment: @ScottBoston you can replace the `lambda x: x.max() - x.min()` with just `np.ptp`

Comment: @user3483203 Oh.  nice.  Thanks.    I wasn't aware of such a simple numpy method.

Comment: @Newbielp  I think I understand what you are asking for now.  Filter rows in the dataframe for max and min values with in each group.

Comment: @Scott, thanks Scott, I try to work on your suggestion. I am getting some errors.

Error with first option: Cannot sort by duplicate column id, str(x), .sort_values(['id','quality'])

Error with second option: Cannot sort by duplicate column id,str(x), .sort_values(['id','quality'])

But I will find examples with "transform" to work on it.